Headers not appearing in Article?
I'm typesetting some anglican chant psalms using LaTeX using: https://github.com/gregrs-uk/anglican-chant-template
Is there something about my code or the style file that would stop the headers from showing?
Thank you in advance.

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psalm}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/culle/Documents/Scores/Magnificat Chants} }

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    {\Large \textbf{Psalm 1}}\\
    \textit{Beatus vir, qui non abiit.}
    \begin{flushright}
        Beale
    \end{flushright}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.99]{Beale in A Minor.png}
\end{center}

% override width of verse text because these lines are quite short
\setlength\textamount{14cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{psalm} % override number of first verse (optional)
    
\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{\textbf{Bl\syl{e}ss\syl{e}d is the man that hath not walked in the counsel of the ungodly, * \breaklongline 
    nor stood in the | way of | sinners}}
{}{\textbf{and hath not | sat_in the | seat_of the | scornful.}}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mf}}{\textbf{But his delight is in the law of the Lord}}
{}{\textbf{and in his law will he exercise himself day and night.}}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{p}}{And he shall be like a tree planted | by the | water-side}
{}{that will bring forth his | fruit in | due | season.}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{His leaf also | shall not | wither}
{}{and look, * whatsoever he | d\syl{o}\syl{e}th, | it shall | prosper.}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{f}}{As for the ungodly, it is not | so with | them}
{}{but they are like the chaff, * \breaklongline
     which the wind scattereth a | way_from the | face of_the | earth.\vspace{0.7em}}

\vs{\quad}{Therefore the ungodly shall not be able to | stand_in the | judgement}
{}{neither the sinners in the congre | gation | of the | righteous.}\\


\vs{\second}{\textbf{But the Lord knoweth the | way_of the | righteous}}
{}{\textbf{and the | way of_the un | godly_shall | perish.}}

\stanzagap

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{Glory | be_to the | Father,}}
        {}{\textbf{and to the Son | and_to the | Holy | Ghost;}}

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{As it was in the beginning, is now, and ever shall be}}
        {}{\textbf{world without end. Amen}}

\end{psalm}
\end{center}

\end{document}

\usepackage{array}



% HORIZONTAL SPACING

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% amount of space for notes e.g. dynamics and Full
\newlength\notesamount
\setlength\notesamount{4.5em}

% amount of space for verse numbers
\newlength\versenumamount
\setlength\versenumamount{1.5em}

% amount of space for verse text
\newlength\textamount
\setlength\textamount{20cm}

% amount to indent second half of each verse
\newlength\indentamount
\setlength\indentamount{1em}



% VERTICAL SPACING

% vertical space between verses
\newlength\versesepamount
\setlength\versesepamount{0.7em}

% vertical space between sections of psalm
\newlength\stanzagapamount
\setlength\stanzagapamount{1.2em}



% define right-aligned paragraph column for use below
\newcolumntype{R}[1]
    {>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

% verse number
\newcounter{VerseCounter}

% environment for psalm text
\newenvironment{psalm}[1][1]
{
    % number of first verse
    \setcounter{VerseCounter}{#1}
    \begin{tabular}{ R{\notesamount} R{\versenumamount} p{\textamount} }
}
{
    \end{tabular}
}



% below we set some characters as 'active' characters,
% allowing them to be defined as macros

% bar line
\catcode`|=\active
\newcommand{|}{\textbar}

% dot for change of note (use instead of space between words)
\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{_}
    {\hspace{0.15em}$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$\hspace{0.15em}}

% pause between words
\newcommand{\ps}
    {*\space}

% dynamics style
\newcommand{\dyn}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}

% second half of chant
\newcommand{\second}{$\dagger$}

% dot above letter to denote syllable
\newcommand{\syl}[1]{$\dot{\textrm{#1}}$}



% verses use the following columns:
% dynamics and full markings | verse numbers | verse text

% normal verse
\newcommand{\vs}[4]{#1 & \theVerseCounter.\stepcounter{VerseCounter} &
    #2\thinspace :\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% verse without gap in middle
\newcommand{\vscontinue}[4]{#1 & \theVerseCounter.\stepcounter{VerseCounter} &
    #2\thinspace : \raisebox{-0.08em}{\large{$\longrightarrow$}}\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% verse without verse number e.g. Gloria
\newcommand{\vsnonums}[4]{#1 & & #2\thinspace :\\
    #3 & &\hspace{\indentamount}#4\\[\versesepamount]}

% break a long line and indent appropriately
\newcommand{\breaklongline}{\newline\hbox{}\hspace{2\indentamount}}

% gap to signify a new section of the psalm
\newcommand{\stanzagap}{\vspace{\stanzagapamount}\\[-12pt]}


You use \pagestyle{empty} so that's what you get (no headers and footers in that style).

Your document uses \pagestyle{empty} that suppresses the headers and footers. If you remove that line you should get your header and footer back (though the header is empty for your MWE).
The following should show a page number at the bottom of the page that tells you that you're seeing headers and footers now (note that I don't have your image, hence I used example-image-duck instead):
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psalm}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/culle/Documents/Scores/Magnificat Chants} }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    {\Large \textbf{Psalm 1}}\\
    \textit{Beatus vir, qui non abiit.}
    \begin{flushright}
        Beale
    \end{flushright}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.99]{example-image-duck}%{Beale in A Minor.png}
\end{center}

% override width of verse text because these lines are quite short
\setlength\textamount{14cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{psalm} % override number of first verse (optional)
    
\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{\textbf{Bl\syl{e}ss\syl{e}d is the man that hath not walked in the counsel of the ungodly, * \breaklongline 
    nor stood in the | way of | sinners}}
{}{\textbf{and hath not | sat_in the | seat_of the | scornful.}}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mf}}{\textbf{But his delight is in the law of the Lord}}
{}{\textbf{and in his law will he exercise himself day and night.}}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{p}}{And he shall be like a tree planted | by the | water-side}
{}{that will bring forth his | fruit in | due | season.}

\vs{\quad\dyn{mp}}{His leaf also | shall not | wither}
{}{and look, * whatsoever he | d\syl{o}\syl{e}th, | it shall | prosper.}\\


\vs{\quad\dyn{f}}{As for the ungodly, it is not | so with | them}
{}{but they are like the chaff, * \breaklongline
     which the wind scattereth a | way_from the | face of_the | earth.\vspace{0.7em}}

\vs{\quad}{Therefore the ungodly shall not be able to | stand_in the | judgement}
{}{neither the sinners in the congre | gation | of the | righteous.}\\


\vs{\second}{\textbf{But the Lord knoweth the | way_of the | righteous}}
{}{\textbf{and the | way of_the un | godly_shall | perish.}}

\stanzagap

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{Glory | be_to the | Father,}}
        {}{\textbf{and to the Son | and_to the | Holy | Ghost;}}

        \vsnonums{\quad}{\textbf{As it was in the beginning, is now, and ever shall be}}
        {}{\textbf{world without end. Amen}}

\end{psalm}
\end{center}

\end{document}


